# Make second word capital in a string

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, charat

I don't really know how to explain the problem. I do have a scanner imported after the package. I'm not sure if you can stack methods, and if you can I'm definitely doing it wrong.

```java
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");

String name = console.next();
name.trim();
name.toUpperCase(name.substring(name.charAt(name.indexOf(" "))));

System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
```

Comment: just use the split method to get all the separate words.

Comment: How do I do that? I just started learning a few weeks ago.

Comment: `String` is immutable. `name.trim()` doesn't make any sense

Comment: @ThomasHuppert, Could you please clarify what your input is and what you expect?

Comment: @ddsultan its supposed to be able to capitalize the second word in any string. an example would be Sherlock Holmes to Sherlock HOLMES

Comment: Emphasizing @ChristophS.'s point: `String#trim` (or any string op with a `String` return, like `String#toUpperCase`) will very likely return a _new_ string, leaving the old one unchanged. You need to re-assign the results.

Comment: Did I get it right? You want to print the input "john doe" as "john Doe"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the String into the first word and second word based on the `indexOf(" ")`

Capitalize the second word using `toUpperCase`

Concatenate both words together using `+`

```
name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" ")) + name.substring(name.indexOf(" ")).toUpperCase();
```

*Note: Not sure if you are required to handle invalid input, but this code would only work assuming a valid two-word name is entered, with a space in-between*

Also, make sure to change `console.next()` to `console.nextLine()` to ensure you retrieve the entire line of input

Answer (score 0):

`String` is **immutable** in Java.

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your first name and last name: ");

    String firstName = upperCaseFirstLetter(scan.next().trim());
    String lastName = upperCaseFirstLetter(scan.next().trim());

    System.out.println("Your name first name: " + firstName);
    System.out.println("Your name last name: " + lastName);
}

private static String upperCaseFirstLetter(String name) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
    String name = console.nextLine();
    String[] words = name.split(" ");
    words[1] = capitalizeWord(words[1]);
    name = String.join(" ", words);
    System.out.println("Your name is: " + name);
}

private static String capitalizeWord(String s) {
    s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    return s;
}
```

At first you split the input into a `String` array. Then you replace the first character of the 2nd (index 1) element and join the array back to a `String`.

Input: john doe, Output: john Doe

Answer (score 0):

[String is immutable](https://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string#:%7E:text=In%20Java%2C%20String%20objects%20are,new%20String%20object%20is%20created.) in java so if you want to "change" a Strig variable value, you need to reassign it to itself. I think a good approach to prepare more than 2 input, many people has middle name e.g.
This function split the input into parts then make the first letter uppercase then return the whole name after concat them with space.

```
 public String capitalizeName(String name) {
    String[] nameParts = name.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < nameParts.length; i++) {
        nameParts[i] = nameParts[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + nameParts[i].substring(1);
    }
    return String.join(" ", nameParts);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to make the String a String array using the `split(regex)`-method. It will split up a string into a String array, breaking them up at regex.
For example:

```
String text = "This is a text.";
String textArray = text.split(" ");

for(String element : textArray)
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

will print

```
This
is
a
text.
```

If you got a String[] like that, you can choose the second String (index 1 of array) and capitalize it. You can do so in a foreach loop, for example.

```
String text = "This is a text.";
text = text.trim(); // if you want to trim it.
String[] textArray = text.split(" ");

String newText = "";
    
int index = 0;
    
for(String element : textArray)
{
    if(index == 1)
    {
        element = element.toUpperCase();
    }
    newText = newText + element + " ";
    index++;
}
    
System.out.println(newText);
```

If you want to handle errors, you can put in in a try-catch-block like this.

```
try
{
    [Your code]
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("An error occured.");
}
```

This is, of course, not a very short way to do it. However, it's easy to understand and it can handle even a string consisting of several words.